# EXTJS Passing Form Fields and Assigning Values to Variables in Controller

Tags: javascript, extjs5

I'm trying to create a login form that mimics the call to a server and "authenticates" a users information.

Here's my Login.js code. this is the form I created:

```
Ext.define("ies.view.login.Login",{
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'login',

requires: [
    'ies.view.login.LoginController',
    'Ext.form.Panel'
],

controller: 'login',
bodyPadding: 60,
draggable: false,
title: 'Login Window',
closable: false,
autoShow: true,

items: {
    xtype: 'form',
    reference: 'form',
    itemId: 'LogInForm',
    method: 'post',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'username',
        fieldLabel: 'Username',
        itemId: 'username',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'password',
        itemId: 'passwords',
        inputType: 'password',
        fieldLabel: 'Password',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        hideEmptyLabel: false,
        value: 'Enter any non-blank password'
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Login',
        formBind: true,
        itemId: 'submit',
        listeners: {
            click: 'onLoginClick'
        }
    }],


}
});
```

This is my controller code:

```
Ext.define('ies.view.login.LoginController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.login',
    onLoginClick: function(){
        //var username = form.down('textfield[name=username]').getValue();
        //var password = form.down('textfield[name=password]').getValue();
        //get form field values
        var username = this.lookupReference('username');
        var password = this.lookupReference('password');
        console.log(username + ' ' + password);
        // This would be the ideal location to verify the user's credentials via 
        // a server-side lookup. We'll just move forward for the sake of this example.

/********************************************/
if ((username === 'carol' || username === 'denise' || username === 'coley' || username === 'yegappan' || username === 'julie' || username === 'dawn' || username === 'yvonne' || username === 'chuck' || username === 'belinda' || username === 'atlante' || username === 'blake' || username === 'ernie' || username === 'Patrick.Dwyer') && password === 'password1'){
/********************************************/


        // Set the localStorage value to true
        localStorage.setItem("TutorialLoggedIn", true);
        console.log("Atuthenticated");

        // Remove Login Window
        this.getView().destroy();

        // Add the main view to the viewport
        Ext.widget('app-main');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("displayfield-1014-inputEl").innerHTML = "Authentication Failed";
        console.log("Not authenticated");
    }
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how to pass the form fields and assign them to the username and password variables in the controller code. All help is really apreciated. Thanks!

I'm using EXTJS v 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` and `itemId` aren't relevant here. Instead, use the `reference` property in conjunction with `lookupReference`.

Comment: Hey thanks for that quick reply. I added that reference property to the fields with username and password as the reference and the console.log message is: [object] [object]. Am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, looks like I was missing the `getValue();` at the end of the `this.lookupReference('password');`. full code:

`var password = this.lookupReference('password').getValue();`